# Embedding Hermitian forms into Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-norms, hermitian

Let $H$ be a nondegenerate, not positive definite, Hermitian form on a complex vector space $V$ such that
$$|H(x,y)|\le u(x)u(y)\tag{B}$$
for some map $u:V\to R_+$ with $u(\lambda x)=|\lambda|u(x)$ for $u\in V$, $\lambda \in C$.

Clearly, condition $(\textrm{B})$ is necessary for the existence of a Euclidean norm on $V$ (defined in the standard way from a positive definite Hermitian form on $V$) such that
$$|H(x,y)|\le \|x\|\,\|y\|.$$
Condition $(\textrm{B})$ is sufficient (and indeed superfluous) in the finite-dimensional case. But what happens in infinite dimensions?

Comment: When the omission of a hypothesis is central to a statement it is a good idea to emphasize it.  It would have saved me a lot of time if the question said "Let $H$ be a *not necessarily positive* Hermitian form..."

Answer (score 2):

Since I posed the question I found that the book

- J. Bognár, Indefinite inner product spaces, Springer 1974

has a counterexample in infinite dimensions; see his Example 5.6, p.90.